# Why list show strange behaviour?

Tags: c#, .net, list, generics, entity-framework-4

Work on  Vs2010 EF,C#.

Have two list(oLisTranItem,oListTaxItem) ,need to copy one list properties values in another list ,then I need to work on new list.Problem is after copy content element one list to another list any type of changes impact on both list ,why this happen ,I just change on list but changes occur in both list
Please check my bellow syntax.

```
            List<TransactionItem> oLisTranItem = new List<TransactionItem>();
            List<TransactionItem> oListTaxItem = new List<TransactionItem>();

            oLisTranItem = _TransactionItem;
            oListTaxItem = _TransactionItemTax;

            TransactionItem tmpItem = new TransactionItem();

            tmpItem = oLisTranItem.Where(item => item.QuotationDetailID == quotationDetailID && item.Action != Entity.ActionMode.Delete && item.IsDeleted == false).FirstOrDefault();

            if (tmpItem.IsNotNull())
            {

                tmpItem.Action = Entity.ActionMode.Add;
                oListTaxItem.Add(tmpItem);

            }
            else
            {
                _TransactionItemTax = new List<TransactionItem>();
            }

            int nCounter = 5;

            foreach (TransactionItem item in oListTaxItem)
            {


                if (item.QuotationTaxID ==0)
                {
                    nCounter = nCounter + 1;

                    item.QuotationTaxID = nCounter;


                }
    }
```

Please help me to identify why this problem aries,how to solve this problem.

If have any query please ask,Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TransactionItem is probably a class, right? And not a struct.

Every type that's a class is, by default, a reference type. That means what you have in the lists are not the real values of the transaction items, but references (think C++ pointers) to those values. So when you copy data from one list to the other, you're just copying references.

You need to [clone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloning_%28programming%29) the items from one list to another. Give your class a method to clone instances, and use that method to copy items from one list to another.